# Do I have 40 Amp breakers here?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Most of my breakers are 15A. Where needed I am seeing them paired and then the end of the switch is marked 30. I seem to have a pair of two like in the picture--the switch end shows 40. Does this amean that this is a pair of 20 circuits grouped together?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it never works that way.  Two 20A circuits don't make a 40A circuit. A 30A breaker does not mean two 15A circuits.

When two 15A or 20A circuits are combined on a single cable sharing a neutral (called a MWBC), they use a double-wide, common-throw breaker like that, but it's a 15A or 20A breaker.  It must stay on this style of breaker with a common throw; never put it on separate breakers *and never, ever put it on a twin/duplex aka "double-stuff" breaker as that will create a fire hazard*.

Other than that, double-wide breakers mean the circuit takes 240V.  (double voltage for big appliances).

- 30A means it takes 30A @ 240V, or 7200W - that is for dryers, water heaters, air conditioners, and mid-size RVs.
- 40A means it takes 40A @ 240V, or 9600W - that is for ranges, generally.

A 15A breaker could be a lot of things. Small welder, tanning bed, aforementioned MWBC, etc.  Given two of them right next to each other, I would speculate the house was wired for window air conditioners in multiple rooms.  I wouldn't trash those circuits; they could be useful.